# How to add custom field in Odoo Enterprise's reports

Tags: odoo, customization, enterprise

I have added some custom fields to the model account.move and I want to add these fields in the following Odoo Enterprise reports:

- Accounting/Reporting/Partner ledger
- Accounting/Reporting/Aged receivable
- Accounting/Reporting/Aged payable

I did not find how to add fields to this kind of reports and they are way different than the regular views

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official odoo documentation for [qweb reports](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html).

It looks roughly like this:

```
<t t-inherit="base.template" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//tr[1]" position="after">
        <tr><td>new cell</td></tr>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

Set `t-inherit-mode="extension"` to modify an existing template. If you would set it to `primary` you would create a new template. From there on you can work with the familiar odoo `xpath` logic.

Keep in mind that this is a templating language with python support. So to actually print a field you first need to find the variable in the parent report (the mother `recordset` is usually called `doc`, `order` or something like this depending on the report). To display it you would do something like this:

```
<p><t t-out="order.name"/></p>
```

Also make sure to open the correct version of the documentation. There have been some changes to reports in recent versions.